# why add cv-qualifiers to value arguments in declaration

Tags: c++, declaration, qualifiers

I recently found out that you can add and remove cv-qualifier from value arguments in a function declaration and it's implementation. For instance:

*F.h*

```
f(const int i);
```

*F.cpp*

```
f(int i) { i++; }
```

*test.cpp*

```
#include "F.h"
f(0);
```

The f(int i) implementation will be called. Since its a copy by value, I see no problems with the code compiling. But can anyone imagine a case, where it's somehow useful to add the **const** to the declaration as done above? Why is it possible at all? Maybe someone can give a more useful application?

Comment: I immediately know it isn't being modified.

Comment: but then the declaration `f(const int i)` is lying.

Comment: @DaBrain Is it really lying? It's taking in a copy of the argument, so from an outside perspective there's no way for the caller to know whether the parameter actually was modified or not.

Comment: @DaBrain, Oh, apologies. I missed the point of the question. `const` is typically left off of the declaration and only put in the definition because it adds no value to the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top-level CV qualifiers on function arguments are ignored, i.e. they are not part of the function signature. Rather, if you will, they are part of the *implementation* of the function, since they qualify the local *variables* corresponding to the formal function parameters. Therefore, if it pleases you, you may qualify function parameters in the function definition:

```
int power(int val, int n, int base);

int power(int val, int n, const int base)
{
    while (n --> 0) val *= base;
    return val;
}
```

Some people find it offensive if the definition has different-looking function parameters from the declaration, though. It's a matter of taste and style. The benefits of qualifying the arguments are probably small, though there is some value for the implementation in documenting that you don't plan to change a variable.

Comment: Is there really value from a user's perspective, though? The only person who cares whether it changes should be the one reading the body. Unless you are in fact talking about the definition, in which case these aren't the droids you're looking for.

Comment: @chris: The "user" either wouldn't see the definition, or if she does, would benefit from the documented intent of how the variables are to be used.

Comment: Does it mean, as a general guideline, if the declaration is separated from the definition you should always skip cv-qualifier for value arguments because they are ignored anyway?

Comment: @DaBrain: In the declaration, definitely, since the qualifiers are not part of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Some people like to state in their definition that they are not going to change a parameter even though it is only visible locally. For example:

```
void f(int);
void f(int const);

void f(int const x) {
    x = 3; // ERROR!
}
```

The definition is the function which was just declared, i.e., there is no change on the signature (well, unless you happen to use Sun's CC which actually takes the `const` into account for the mangled name but that's just an error). All three signatures declare exactly the same function and the `const` only affects the body of the definition if it is used in the definition's declaration.

Comment: So const makes sense in the implementation, but what about the declaration alone?